# How to build and deploy a .Net application using XLDeploy?

Tags: xl-deploy

I am new to XLDeploy and just for learning I am trying to Build and Deploy a sample .Net application using XLDeploy.

As per the documentation I need to create a DAR file that is nothing but a .Zip folder which contains the files to be deployed and an "deployit-manifest.xml" file which contains the IIS related configurations.

So, I kept the files to be deployed along with a HelloWorld.Zip folder and placed both of them in Application.DAR folder (I created this manually). When trying to import this package into XLDeploy GUI, it says that the package is not valid.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The default XLD installation contains a folder `importablePackages` that has a demo application in it called `NerdDinner`. That can be used as a reference.

```
/opt/xld/server/importablePackages # ls 
NerdDinner     PetClinic-ear  PetClinic-war  readme.txt
```